# (operationalizable) Cost measure for small problems

Tags: complexity-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

For what I know of complexity measures in CS, they are aimed at rather large problems. With today's computing power, most people don't care about comparing the complexity of simple problems as they would all be solved in about the same time.

Yet, I turn out to be interested in some cost measures for small problems. For instance, although both `12 + 14` and `123503 + 589034` can be solved in the blink of an eye by today's computers, there seems to be a sense in which `123503 + 589034` is still more "costly" than `12 + 14`.

So **my question is** : do you know of any such cost measures that would be appropriate for such small size problems?

**Note 1** : I am interested in rather general answer for all kinds of problems, the addition one being just an example.

**Note 2** : the best I have found so far is Kolmogorov's complexity, but for what I understand of it, it seems awfully hard to operationalize. *First* it appears to be dependent on the reference language, and *second*, once a language is chosen, it seems really hard to prove that a description of a string is of minimal length.

- Do you know of any measure which would be easier to implement?
- Am I missing something about Kolmogorov's complexity and is it easier to implement than I suggest?

Comment: Related questions : http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32114/what-problem-cannot-be-solved-by-a-short-program, http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19615/what-is-an-estimation-of-the-kolmogorov-complexity-for-the-first-n-integers

Comment: The first step is to figure out what you're trying to measure.  What do you mean by complexity?  What do you mean by small?  What do you want to do with it?  Before you can design or select a metric, you first need to know what you're trying to measure...

Comment: @D.W. : At this point, I am not sure I can give a good answer to your questions. I understand that it would make the question much better and much easier to answer. But I don't have anything more precise in mind that what I wrote. Sorry if it makes the question too vague, feel free to vote to close if you feel like it cannot be answered in its current state.

Comment: Complexity theory deals with problems, whereas you're talking about properties of individual instances. It's not clear what that means, since any individual instance can be solved in linear time. For example, `sum (x,y) { If (x=123503 and y=589034) return 712537; else return x+y; }` Complexity has to be over a class of instances.

Comment: Get rid of the term "complexity" and use "cost measure". Then, [analyse the algorithm *rigorously*](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) w.r.t. this cost measure. If you get an exact result like "A needs $17n + 5$ arithmetic operations on input $n$", great. *Often you won't*, and that's why we use asymptotics -- the calculations are more manageable.

Answer (score 2):

When we talk about complexity in computer science we are usually talking about asymptotic complexity. We are interested in characterizing the complexity of a process as the size of its inputs increase. This is useful because it abstracts away implementation-specific characteristics, such as processor speed or architecture or available memory. So while asymptotic analysis does, in this sense, concern itself with "large problems," its intent is not so much to treat large problems as it is to provide a meaningful metric for comparing algorithms in terms of time and space efficiency.

Kolmogorov complexity does not, to my knowledge, find applications in the practical analysis of programs or computational processes. It is an information-theoretic measure concerned with the minimal length of data as represented in a computational system. In so far as using it in any sort of "operational" analysis like those you've proposed, the big roadblock is that [the Kolmogorov complexity of an arbitrary string is not, in general, computable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Uncomputability_of_Kolmogorov_complexity)!

It's difficult to pin down exactly what you're asking for, but it sounds more akin to counting CPU cycles required to execute a series of instructions. Back in the old days, when assembly language on punch-cards was the state-of-the-art, this was a fairly common technique used for optimization.

As it applies to your example, adding two numbers would involve loading them, bitwise, into registers, performing the addition, and storing the result. If the addends required more bits to represent than the size of the registers, you'd have to do it piecewise, loading and storing intermediate results as needed. You can count the cycles needed to execute tasks of varying 'difficulties' (adding two 1-byte numbers vs. adding two 2-byte numbers, for example) and compare them to give some sense of how much more or less 'complicated' the execution of a given sequence of instructions is.

It's not complexity in the traditional CS sense, but it would be a quantifiable, implementable metric. Donald Knuth has a program [here](http://mmix.cs.hm.edu/tools/mmstort/) that counts the cycles required to execute MMIX programs, as an example of such an implementation.